# Program to capitalise starting letter of each word

Tags: c, file

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    fp=fopen ("input.txt","r");
    fp1=fopen ("output.txt","w+");
    char a;
    while ((a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        fputc(a,fp1);
    }
    char b=fgetc(fp1);
    int e='a';
    int f='z';
    if (b>=e && b<=f){
        b-=32;
        fputc(b,fp1);
    }
    char c;
    while ((c=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){
        if (c==' '){
            c=fgetc(fp1);
            if (c>=e && c<=f){
                c-=32;
                fputc (c,fp1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

C was invented to write an operating system called UNIX.
C is a successor of B language which was introduced around 1970
The language was formalized in 1988 by the American National Standard Institue (ANSI).
By 1973 UNIX OS almost totally written in C.
Today C is the most widely used System Programming Language.
Most of the state of the art software have been implemented using C.
Easy to learn
Structured language
It produces efficient programs.
It can handle low-level activities.
It can be compiled on a variety of computers.

Sample output:

C Was Invented To Write An Operating System Called UNIX.
C Is A Successor Of B Language Which Was Introduced Around 1970
The Language Was Formalized In 1988 By The American National Standard Institue (ANSI).
By 1973 UNIX OS Almost Totally Written In C.
Today C Is The Most Widely Used System Programming Language.
Most Of The State Of The Art Software Have Been Implemented Using C.
Easy To Learn
Structured Language
It Produces Efficient Programs.
It Can Handle Low-level Activities.
It Can Be Compiled On A Variety Of Computers.

However on compiling, I am getting same output as input. Can someone help?

Comment: It is probably unnecessary to put an example this big (you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe edit your post to make it samller?

Comment: Because it is said that w+, r+ and a+ are both read and write.

Comment: What did you think the fragment `    while ((a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        fputc(a,fp1);
    }` would do?

Comment: @KenWhite Wouldn't char get typecasted when doing comparison/

Comment: @infixed It will put all characters from input.txt to output.txt

Comment: C already as a function `toupper` that turns a character to uppercase if it's a lowercase alphabetic character, so you wouldn't have to do the checking and the `-= 32`.

Comment: But I don't see why you first write a simple copy and THEN convert it instead of converting on the fly.

Comment: @programmer,  Wasn't your complaint "I am getting same output as input.".  That seems like a restatement of "put all characters from input.txt to output.txt" to me

Comment: There are 2 issues, which sort of cancel each other.  Since you write all the data first, you need to rewind if you want to read it.  But that's just bad design.  Don't do that.  Instead of writing all the data and the making a second pass, just do the conversion on the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating things. This would do:

```
FILE *fp=fopen ("input.txt","r");
FILE *fp1=fopen ("output.txt","w+");    

int capitalize = 1;
int c; // int, not char

while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    char a = c;

    if(capitalize) {
        a = toupper(c);
        capitalize = 0;
    }

    if(isspace(a)
        capitalize = 1;

    fputc(a, fp1);
}
```

Comment: Using `isspace()` would fail to capitalize "low-level" into "Low-Level" because "-" isn't a space.  You'd want `!isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

Near the beginning of your program you have code that says

```
while ((a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
    fputc(a,fp1);
}
```

That literally copies all the characters from input to output, letting any future fgets to get EOF

Thats why your output is your input

If you are trying to do a two pass thing, that is a lot of extra work.  Please note that reading and write both affect where your file pointer is, where I/O will occur.  A read will not leave it where you want the write to go.

You'd need to take that into account for modifying your copied output file in-place.

A better idea is to do the capitalization as you copy.

Answer (score 0):

Seems too complicated.

Try something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
bool wasAlpha = false; 
while ((a=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
{ 
  bool isAlpha = IsAlpha(a); 
  if (isAlpha && !wasAlpha) 
    fputc(ToUpper(a),fp1); 
  else 
    fputc(a,fp1); 
  wasAlpha = isAlpha; 
}
...
```